# Crossfilter of data not working using function

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I have a data with id and distance like the following

```
var data=[
{"id":1,"distance":0.506},
{"id":2,"distance":0.506},
{"id":3,"distance":0.506},
{"id":4,"distance":0.506},
{"id":5,"distance":0.506},
{"id":6,"distance":0.106},
{"id":7,"distance":0.0065},
{"id":8,"distance":0.106},
{"id":9,"distance":0.106}
]
```

I want to crossfilter the data so that only the data whose distance is > 0.2 remains after the filter. I am using the folllowing code to do the crossfilter. But its not working.

```
var ndr=crossfilter(data);
var fild=ndr.dimension(function(d){if(d.distance>=0.2){return d;}});
data=fild.top(Infinity);
```

So the output data should be the following

```
var filtereddata=[
    {"id":1,"distance":0.506},
    {"id":2,"distance":0.506},
    {"id":3,"distance":0.506},
    {"id":4,"distance":0.506},
    {"id":5,"distance":0.506}
    ]
```

Can anyone help me to fix the problem?

Comment: I have also added a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/23n15t86/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. This is the working code

```
var ndr=crossfilter(data);
var fild=ndr.dimension(function(d){return d;});
var fildata=fild.filterFunction(function(d){if(d.distance>=0.2){return d;}});
data=fild.top(Infinity);
```